Receiver stops receiving data using Lora (no LoRaWAN)
I have a very basic setup where I have two devices, one is sending the other one is receiving data and displaying some message on sd1306 display.
The payload is simple: "Helloworld".
When the devices are close to each other I can successfully send as many messages I want, however when I go to a remote area where it is likely that the receiver will miss some messages a weird thing happens. Sometimes the receiver receives 3/20 messages, and when I'm back home with my sender device, the receiver is not able to receive any data even when the devices are next to each other. Like it is blocked or something.
This situation is reproducible, does not happen if the devices are in the "range". I'm in the urban area, however from what I know I'm the only one in the neighborhood who uses Lora.
I'm using LoRa-E5 mini STM32WLE5JC
This is a Zephyr sample code - as you can see nothing special happens here:
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2019 Manivannan Sadhasivam
 *
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */


#include <zephyr/device.h>
#include <zephyr/drivers/lora.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <zephyr/sys/util.h>
#include <zephyr/drivers/display.h>
#include <zephyr/drivers/gpio.h>
#include <zephyr/kernel.h>
#include <lvgl.h>



#define LOG_LEVEL CONFIG_LOG_DEFAULT_LEVEL
#include <zephyr/logging/log.h>
LOG_MODULE_REGISTER(app);


// App 
static uint32_t msg_recv_count;


// Radio
#define DEFAULT_RADIO_NODE DT_ALIAS(lora0)
BUILD_ASSERT(DT_NODE_HAS_STATUS(DEFAULT_RADIO_NODE, okay),
         "No default LoRa radio specified in DT");


#define MAX_DATA_LEN 10
const struct device *const lora_dev = DEVICE_DT_GET(DEFAULT_RADIO_NODE);


// Display
const struct device *display_dev = DEVICE_DT_GET(DT_CHOSEN(zephyr_display));
lv_obj_t *msg_sent_label;
lv_obj_t *msg_count_label;


int lra_base_lora_config(void)
{
    struct lora_modem_config config;
    int ret;


    if (!device_is_ready(lora_dev)) {
        LOG_ERR("%s Device not ready", lora_dev->name);
        return 0;
    }


    config.frequency = 868100000; //865100000
    config.bandwidth = BW_125_KHZ;
    config.datarate = SF_12;
    config.preamble_len = 8;
    config.coding_rate = CR_4_5;
    config.iq_inverted = false;
    config.public_network = false;
    config.tx_power = 13;
    config.tx = true;


    ret = lora_config(lora_dev, &config);
    if (ret < 0) {
        LOG_ERR("LoRa config failed");
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}


int display_init(void)
{ 
    if (!device_is_ready(display_dev)) {
        LOG_ERR("Device not ready, aborting test");
        return 0;
    }


    msg_sent_label = lv_label_create(lv_scr_act());
    lv_label_set_text(msg_sent_label, "lra-base(recv)");
    lv_obj_align(msg_sent_label, LV_ALIGN_CENTER, 0, 0);


    msg_count_label = lv_label_create(lv_scr_act());
    lv_label_set_text(msg_count_label, "");
    lv_obj_align(msg_count_label, LV_ALIGN_BOTTOM_MID, 0, 0);


    lv_task_handler();
    display_blanking_off(display_dev);


    return 0;
}


void lra_base_display_set_text(void)
{
    char count_str[11] = {0};
    sprintf(count_str, "%d", msg_recv_count);
    lv_label_set_text(msg_sent_label, "Msg recv");
    lv_label_set_text(msg_count_label, count_str);
}


void lora_base_display_set_err(void)
{
    lv_label_set_text(msg_sent_label, "error");
}


int main(void)
{
    int len;
    uint8_t data[MAX_DATA_LEN + 1] = {0};
    int16_t rssi;
    int8_t snr;


    if (lra_base_lora_config() != 0) {
        return -1;
    }


    if (display_init() != 0) {
        return -1;
    }


    while (1) {
        LOG_INF("Synchronous reception");
        len = lora_recv(lora_dev, data, MAX_DATA_LEN, K_FOREVER,
                &rssi, &snr);
        if (len < 0) {
            LOG_ERR("LoRa receive failed");
            lora_base_display_set_err();
            continue;
        }


        LOG_INF("Received data: %s (RSSI:%ddBm, SNR:%ddBm)",
            data, rssi, snr);
        ++msg_recv_count;


        lra_base_display_set_text();


        lv_task_handler();
        k_sleep(K_MSEC(10));
    }


    return 0;
}

Any idea why does the device stop receiving? Is it something specific to LoRa that I'm not aware?

Just for people who experienced the same issue. The problem was that driver did not handle RX errors such as CRC errors and so on. I've already fixed it and delivered to Zephyr. Should be available in Zephyr release later than 3.7

Can you point to PR that fixes this issue? Thanks

Sure this is it https://github.com/zephyrproject-rtos/zephyr/pull/76611
